# C# how can i compute fine by date and data coming from the database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

How can i compute fine?

> by date1 < date2

the date1 is the date from the database and the date is the date now how to compute it
 and preventing to re-compute it with that same date, and this is the only code i am using to compute fine.

```
private void frmMainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                DateTime datetoday = DateTime.Today;
                conn.Open();
                string getdate = "update tblSBorrowList set [Fine] =Fine+5 where  DATEADD(day,7,[Borrowed Date]) < '@datenow'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getdate, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datenow", datetoday);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

this works but every time i stop and run the program again it add **5**. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: I understand you've got one fine per record, not per user, how is it (the fine) supposed to change over time?

Comment: yes it's by **Record**,  and no it's by date. and i don't know how to make by date and not repeat updating it with the same date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you need to add another column `FineApplied` to your table.

Your SQL condition is **always** true after 7 days, so it will always apply the fine after 7 days, 8 day, 100 days when you run your code

For example if you ran this every day:

6 days overdue: no fine
7 days overdue: add fine
8 days overdue: add fine
...
.
100 days overdue: add fine

Change your query to this:

```
update tblSBorrowList 
set 
[Fine] =Fine+5,
[FineApplied] = 1
where [Borrowed Date] < DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE())
and [FineApplied] = 0
```

This makes sure a fine is applied only once.

You have not explained much about the fine schedule so I've made some assumptions.

Comment: yes it always add 5. if  7> days. the fine schedule is once the user run the program it will update **tblSBorrowList** but prevent  from updating it 1> a day

Comment: thank you i just revise the code you said to me and now it works Fine :)